# Drawable image on a canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-drawable

How can I get an image to a canvas in order to draw on that image?

Answer (score 211):

The good way to draw a Drawable on a canvas is not decoding it yourself but leaving it to the system to do so:

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.foobar, null);
d.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
d.draw(canvas);
```

This will work with all kinds of drawables, not only bitmaps. And it also means that you can re-use that same drawable again if only the size changes.

Comment: How does one use an animation-list (multiple frames) for animation with the canvas approach?

Comment: Very useful! At least when you need just a background picture with no rocket science involved!

Comment: @RichieHH I have my background on a SurfaceView (propably a waste) and that surface view is embedded in a Framelayout and that framelayout contains ImageViews which I then animate - maybe that's an option for you?

Comment: getDrawable(id) is being deprecated, you should either use the ContextCompat call above, or the getDrawable(id, theme) call.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDrawable(int)

Comment: @Saveen: Are you sure? As far as I can remember, this is supposed to work from the earliest versions of Android.

Comment: `setBounds(0, 0, width, height)`

Answer (score 40):

You need to load your image as bitmap:

```
 Resources res = getResources();
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.your_image);
```

Then make the bitmap mutable and create a canvas over it:

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true));
```

You then can draw on the canvas.

Comment: What if my .png is big and it gets cut after being loaded? i.e. I don;t want to have it cropped. It can be bigger than the screen, then I will try to make it zoomable and movable. How may I do that? Thank you so so much!

Comment: @perfectionm1ng look at using BitmapRegionDecoder. It allows partial loading for big images. So you should be able to load only the part of image you're rendering at the moment.

Comment: I have the same problem I am using the code 
Canvas cs = new Canvas(bitmap); 
Resources res = getResources(); 
Bitmap bitmapx = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.overlay_good_full); 

Bitmap bitmapxx = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.overlay_bad_full); 

if(text.equals("Good")) 
{ 
cs.drawBitmap(bitmapx, 0, 0, tPaint); 
} 
else
{
cs.drawBitmap(bitmapxx, 0, 0, tPaint); 
}

Comment: How does creating new canvas object draw on the canvas of onDraw ?

Answer (score 16):

also you can use this way. it will change your big drawble fit to your canvas:

```
Resources res = getResources();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, yourDrawable);
yourCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, yourPaint);
```

Comment: BitmapFactory class doesn't have method "BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Resource, Drawable);"...

Comment: @Crisic I would assume that `yourDrawable` is an integer.

Answer (score 15):

```
Drawable d = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.***)
d.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
d.draw(canvas);
```

Comment: I create Drawable with gerResource().getDrawable(id);

Comment: getDrawable(id) is being deprecated, you should either use the ContextCompat call above, or the getDrawable(id, theme) call.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDrawable(int)

Comment: For me, it was necessary to use `setBounds`. Without it, nothing got displayed.

Answer (score 8):

try this

```
Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap src, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, boolean filter);

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawColor(0xFFAAAAAA);
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

        }
```

Comment: But if i use canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint); it works and it load the saved image on the canvas, but at the same time undo and redo stop working, Check my code http://pastebin.com/cP9w6stm

Answer (score 3):

To preserve the aspect ratio of my vector drawable I did this (in [image]Kotlin):

```kotlin
val drawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.my_vector, null)
val aspectRatio = drawable.intrinsicWidth.toFloat() / drawable.intrinsicHeight
val desiredWidthInPx = 100
val derivedHeightInPx = (desiredWidthInPx / aspectRatio).toInt()
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, desiredWidthInPx, derivedHeightInPx)
drawable.draw(canvas)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
package com.android.jigsawtest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class SurafaceClass extends SurfaceView implements
        SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    Bitmap mBitmap;
Paint paint =new Paint();
    public SurafaceClass(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, paint);

    }

}
```