# Circle of light ontop of bitmap - Android

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I'm trying to create a torch item in my game, that will light bitmaps\bitmap that are behind him in a circle shape (for example torch in terraria), so basically I'm trying to understand how to create a bright circle. example picture made in photoshop: http://puu.sh/evqet/4277f7e2c8.png

anyone has idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There many ways to achieve this. One (fast) is to use the HSL color space and increase the L parameter foe example. I don't know if you are working with RGB if there is an easy way around it.

I guess since you probably wont want to check every pixel in the circle you may need to add a second circle semi-opaque for example which will make the calculation easier for you.

Comment: so I need to check every pixel inside a circle and change the L parameter? what if I want it to be custom light, like yellow torch and blue torch will add some color and light it up?

Comment: Like I said the first method is maybe too demanding but on the semi-opaque you can select a different color as easily instead of a neutral white one, like yellow etc and it will work fine

Comment: I cant find a source code of running on every pixel in a bitmap in a circle shape, i managed to find one for the whole bitmap but not as a circle

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a **transparent PNG sprite** and draw it as a bitmap in your canvas at desidered position.

More info about how-to-do can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176441/drawable-image-on-a-canvas) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801075/android-how-to-apply-mask-on-imageview).

Comment: that won't work, i want the torch to work on any image and while i move it the circle will move with it

Comment: This depends on how you implement it. Just an idea: you can create a stretchable torch sprite and save to a PNG and use it as a MASK while drawing the image by multiplying the image pixel in the "masked" region by a brigther value.

Comment: Uhm I don't really understand you :(

Comment: I've edited the answer by adding one more link. Take a look :)

Comment: I see, but in my case each bitmap is small, they are blocks that connect together into one and ontop of them i want to draw the circle, so it doesn't really work out with my problem.