# hashi a puzzle game, how to output the puzzle

Tags: java, android

I am making a hashi puzzle game. I am using a 2D array for the game board with the number of links as the int in the array. I am iterating through the array twice. What would be the best way to output an image saved into the drawable folder onto the canvas in the position it is meant to be?

```
int gameBoard[][] = {{1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 3, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2, 0, 2}};

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    //i index of the row, there are 5 rows so loop through them all
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        for (int R=0; 5 > R; R++) {
            //j is the position of an element in the row, we have 5.
            if (gameBoard[i][R] == 1) {
                // what here?

            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: changed this, sorry

Comment: And what about `if (gameBoard[i][R] = 1)`? Should that be `== 1`?

Comment: Also `5 < R` won't make that inner loop be entered...

Comment: made these changes

Comment: Okay, so now, what exactly do you mean by "in the position it is meant to be"? What position? You are drawing a Canvas... do you want squares, rectangles, circles?

Comment: the board should be a 5x5 grid, where the numbers are will be ovals with the number inside it, which will indicate the number of connections allowed to each of the items.

Comment: Okay, so what have you tried? I'm sure that reading over the Canvas documentation should tell you how to draw shapes. Forget the nested loop for now. Have you drawn anything?

Comment: i have drawn basic rectangles and basic ovals using the drawRect and drawOval, i was just wondering the best way to output a image from my drawable folder, as i cannot seem to find a way to do so.

Comment: Why can't you just place `ImageView`s?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#drawables-from-images

Comment: does that still work with multiple images? on a game map?

Comment: Actually, I think this is what you're looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22931750/2308683