# setBackgroundResource() covers screen contents

Tags: java, android

I am new to android game programming and I can't seem to find a way to get the background image to stay behind the game, I don't have an xml file for this activity so I added the background in the java code but it is covering the whole game.

Thanks in advance

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        _game = new Game(this);
     // _game.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_ingame);
        setContentView(_game);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Game` is `View` . If you call`setBackgroundResource` on game object the it will set it to games background . And it will scale as per the size of `Game` view .
If you want to set the background to screen and `Game` will be above layer . You can try something like this :-

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FrameLayout frameLayout=new FrameLayout(this);
    frameLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_ingame);
    game = new Game(this);
    frameLayout.addView(game);
    setContentView(frameLayout);
}
```

Comment: setBackgroundResource is deprecated, use setBackground

Comment: `setBackgroundDrawable` is deprecated not  `setBackgroundResource`. Also i am not making a statement about setting background drawable here . There are multiple way to do this .

Comment: Cheers for the answers guys, this way didnt seem to work for me. I just tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176441/drawable-image-on-a-canvas and now its working. Thank you!